# Chrome Extension Message

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just started with creating chrome extensions, below is my code to bring up certain message once I click a button,

```
document.querySelector('.button1').addEventListener('click', onclick, false)
    function onclick () {
   chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, 
        function (tabs) {    
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'Title, line 1, line 2, line 3')
```

My question is in chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'Title, line 1, line 2, line 3')

1. How do I bold text within my message - (Title)?
2. How do I add a line break to move Line 1 to next line?

Comment: I understand, adding a new line is pretty straightforward by \n but how do I bold the text?

Comment: You're sending a text string, which doesn't have such concepts as bold text. It depends on how your message listener will use it. If you assign to `innerHTML` then you can use HTML `<b>` inside your string.